# Onsen UI + sortable list (drag and drop)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

Onsen UI utilizes Hammer.js for gesture detection.
There is a way or there is someone who has tried to make an sortable list?
I tried using as explained here in the documentation:
http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#DetectingFingerGestures
but without success.
Tks David

Comment: please, share a code attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing with AngularJs, you may try to look at these two plugins.

[ng-sortable by a5hik](https://github.com/a5hik/ng-sortable)

[UI.Sortable directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable)

Comment: Tks a lot Trtshen! I try to use the first link. I hope that does not conflict with hammer.js